# How to show GPS latitude/longitude in input in Android application (webview)

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, android, jquery

I develop an Android application with jQuery Mobile 1.9, Cordova 2.4 ... I want to display the coordinate of GPS (lon,lat) in input like in the pictures, I'm tired with this code but it can't display the coordinates. If you know where error is help me please.

[image: html file].

[image: manifest.xml]